# PHP email Script Not Working

Tags: php, html

I have a php email script that has worked with a website  used it on before, but I've moved it over to the re-designed site and when I hit submit the page reloads with this additional text in the url:

> ?name=Lee+Thomas&email=leethomas%40corwenforestry.co.uk&message=message&Submit=Send

Here's the form in the contact.html page:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
 <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" id="name" size="50">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email" size="50">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" cols="50" rows="4" id="message">
    </textarea>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"> <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

And here's the sendmail.php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "number8pie@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "CFR F3 Contact Form";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting CF Racing F3, we will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
?>
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

[EDIT] The problem in block quotes below is now solved, the reset button does exactly that.

> Another issue I'm having is that the Reset button is acting as another
>   Submit/Send button, is there a way I can have the Submit/Send button
>   act as that button?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[EDIT]
Changed the html to remove redundant form tag.

Comment: Remove the `<form>` tag inside the `<table>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is tow `<form>` tag try after remove one stray `<form>` tag

use this

```
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
   <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
```

instead of

```
<form>
 <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Now I get the success message but no email sent to the mentioned account. I also put the proper form tag before the form, for css reasosns, thought I'd let you know if that makes any difference

Comment: it also depends on hosting ..if you have shared it take up to 10 -20 minutes ..so please wait some time even than if not get mail than leave a comment

Comment: No still no email, and it's gmail I'm using to test and every other time I've tested it and it's worked, it's arrived within a minute.

Comment: Ahh balls. My bad, I uploaded it on to a staging part of a live server and it worked. WAMP must be mis-configured to send emails via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Remove top `<form>` tag, you have duplicate

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the first form tage :

```
**<form>**
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<form name="contact" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
```